# How can I add multiple titles on a gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I'm working with a gridview on vb.net for webforms, I have to add titles to specific groups of columns in this table.. but I have not a clue of how to do it, heres an example of what i want:
[image]

"Student info", "Subject info" and "Partial Grades" ARE the titles I need to add.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot have columns within columns... You would probably have to create your own control for this.

Comment: @VisualVincent I'll try by adding html tags inside the gridview

Comment: That will definitely not work. The DataGridView doesn't display HTML and `Visual Basic <> HTML`.

Comment: If you know your way around HTML you could use the `WebBrowser` component and create a HTML table inside it instead.

Comment: A GridView in Asp.Net WebForms can do what you are asking. [See my reply to a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716084/how-to-create-custom-header-in-asp-net-gridview)

Answer (score 1):

Default Datagridview hasnt got an option as u wish.
You can try devexpress (It has got tones of properties in gridcontrol)
You can create your own control acting like your "TITLE LABELS"

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim DataGridView1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
    Dim Column1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Dim Column2 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Dim Column3 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Dim TableLayoutPanel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
    Dim Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Dim Label2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()

    'DataGridView1
    DataGridView1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
    DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Column1, Column2, Column3})
    DataGridView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 78)
    DataGridView1.Name = "DataGridView1"
    DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False
    DataGridView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(397, 228)
    DataGridView1.TabIndex = 0
    DataGridView1.Name = "dgv"
    AddHandler DataGridView1.ColumnWidthChanged, AddressOf DataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged
    '
    'Column1
    '
    Column1.HeaderText = "Column1"
    Column1.Name = "Column1"
    '
    'Column2
    '
    Column2.HeaderText = "Column2"
    Column2.Name = "Column2"
    '
    'Column3
    '
    Column3.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    Column3.HeaderText = "Column3"
    Column3.Name = "Column3"
    '
    'TableLayoutPanel1
    '
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 53.98936!))
    TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 195.0!))
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Label2, 1, 0)
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Label1, 0, 0)
    TableLayoutPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 51)
    TableLayoutPanel1.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
    TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1
    TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50.0!))
    TableLayoutPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(398, 29)
    TableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 1
    TableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.[Single]
    TableLayoutPanel1.Name = "title"
    '
    'Label1
    '
    Label1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None
    Label1.AutoSize = True
    Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(82, 8)
    Label1.Name = "Label1"
    Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
    Label1.TabIndex = 0
    Label1.Text = "Label1"


    '
    'Label2
    '
    Label2.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None
    Label2.AutoSize = True
    Label2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(281, 8)
    Label2.Name = "Label2"
    Label2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
    Label2.TabIndex = 1
    Label2.Text = "Label2"
    '
    'Form1
    '

    Me.Controls.Add(TableLayoutPanel1)
    Me.Controls.Add(DataGridView1)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs)
    Dim title As TableLayoutPanel = CType(Me.Controls("title"), TableLayoutPanel)
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = CType(Me.Controls("dgv"), DataGridView)
    title.ColumnStyles(0).Width = dgv.Columns(0).Width + dgv.Columns(1).Width
    title.ColumnStyles(1).Width = dgv.Columns(2).Width
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: hey, you think you can add a fiddle where I can se the result?

Comment: create new project and paste this whole code to your form1.vb