# Printing a header in all paged and a gridview with true paging

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview, printing, paging

I have a header div like this:

```
 <div id="header" style="width:100%; padding: 6px; margin-right: 20px; border-top-style: dotted; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0.2px; font-family: 'B Yekan'; font-size: 10pt;">
        <p style="display:block;float:right">
            <a style="right:0; font-size: 14pt; margin-right: 10px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMasir" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

and a grid view in a div under the header div as:

```
<div style="float: right; direction: rtl">
                <asp:GridView Font-Names="B Nazanin" Font-Size="10pt" ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server" CellPadding="6" BorderStyle="Double" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="9pt" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
```

and these two dives located in another container div to have the header width same as gridview width:

```
<div style="position:absolute">
    <div id="header" …>
        …
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="griddiv…>
        …
    </div>
</div>
```

so how can i print this page that header repeated in all printed pages as header of gridview and gridview printed with true paging.
i know how to print a single girdview with paging but i don't know how to do it with a header in top if the gird in all pages.
Regards!

Comment: try covert all in pdf using itextsharp... you don't have to save physical file

Comment: You can add additional header rows to GridView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716084/how-to-create-custom-header-in-asp-net-gridview/36727468#36727468

Comment: @fnostro i'm using C# ! this link is for vb. do you know any other source for c#?

Comment: Converting it to C# should be a simple matter.  Just define variables and parameters in C# style, add semi-colons at the end of lines, and explicitly cast where VB is using implicit casts.  I'll post a C# answer here in a bit

Answer (score 0):

C# version of [my VB answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716084/how-to-create-custom-header-in-asp-net-gridview/36727468#36727468):

```
    private void gvExpertRateHistory_PreRender(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        Table InnerTable = (Table)gv.Controls[0];

        if (gv.HeaderRow != null && InnerTable != null)
        {
            GridViewRow hr;

            hr = new GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(1, String.Empty, gv, Alignment:HorizontalAlign.Left));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Requested On", gv, Alignment: HorizontalAlign.Left));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(4, "Review Rates", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(6, "Court Rates", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(6, "Deposition Rates", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(4, "IME Rates", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            InnerTable.Rows.AddAt(0, hr);

            hr = new GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(1, "Expert", gv, Alignment: HorizontalAlign.Left));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Requested By", gv, Alignment: HorizontalAlign.Left));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Hourly", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Flat", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Hourly", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Daily", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Half-Day", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Hourly", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Daily", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Half-Day", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Hourly", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            hr.Cells.Add(NewCell(2, "Flat", gv, "WhiteBorderLB"));
            InnerTable.Rows.AddAt(1, hr);
        }
    }
```

---

```
    private TableHeaderCell NewCell(int colspan,
                                    string text,
                                    GridView gv,
                                    string CssClass = "",
                                    HorizontalAlign Alignment = HorizontalAlign.Center)
    {

        TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();

        thc.HorizontalAlign = Alignment;
        thc.ColumnSpan = colspan;
        thc.Text = text;
        thc.BackColor = gv.HeaderRow.BackColor;
        thc.ForeColor = gv.HeaderRow.ForeColor;
        thc.Font.Bold = true;
        thc.CssClass = CssClass;

        return thc;

    }
```