# Header column with a column span in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

For example, I want to have my header as the following:

```
|       Header Column           |      Header Column2      |
|apple|Microsoft|Android|Dell|HP|Targus|Stack Overflow|Acer|
```

My VB code to add a column is the following:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Clear()
    dt.Columns.Add("apple")
    dt.Columns.Add("Microsoft")
Dim mr As DataRow
    mr = dt.NewRow
    mr("apple") = "Macbook"
    mr("Microsoft") = "Surface Pro"
dt.Rows.Add(mr)
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: you might try Repeater which allows you to do custom design

Comment: how would i use repeater in this situation?

Comment: You can add additional `HeaderRow` to the  Gridview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716084/how-to-create-custom-header-in-asp-net-gridview/36727468#36727468

Comment: how would i be able to use header row in my code. should i just add a header column and then add it to my dt.rows? or am i over thinking?

Comment: you don't modify the datatable. you add an extra header row to the the gridview inner table during the gridview PreRender event. There is an example in my answer in the above SO link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in the RowDataBound event of the GridView. Just simply check if the current row is the header, and if so, set which cells should span.

First make sure the GridView handles the row data bound event.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridView1_RowDataBound">
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

Then, decide which cell should span. After that, hide the cells that the spanned cell will span over.

```
Protected Sub gridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = 3
        e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False
        e.Row.Cells(2).Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Just remember that this hardcoding can lead to problems in the future should any columns be added or removed.

Comment: This needs to be done in PreRender as Databinding doesn't always occur if the datasource is cached.

Comment: @fnostro - Interesting. Though I don't know if I fully follow. Are you referring to [caching data using data source controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227994(v=vs.100).aspx)? If so, I did just give that a test myself to see how that worked. I noticed it did call RowDataBound each time whether or not it used cached data. Are you saying sometimes that may not be the case?

Comment: It depends on your design.  But typically data sources should always be cached, either by using `SqlDataSource` or similar caching control or programatically within the Application Cache.  But cached or not, if you always make a call to `DataBind()` then it's fine to leave it in RowDataBound.  The header will just disappear if you switch to a cached data source (and stop making manual calls to `DataBind()`)

Comment: got it please give this question an upvote i marked this as an answer. it helped. so for future guest mark as upvote thanks